# How to lookup values in R

Tags: r

Can anyone help, I have a data frame (`set_rise`) with each row containing the time of sunset of that day and the time of sunrise the next day. I have a second data frame (`data`) with a column of date/times. I want to create a second column in `data` with a letter corresponding to day or night by taking the date/time in `data` and checking to see if it is or isn't between any of the the times in `set_rise`.

```
#df1- sunset, sunrise times
set_rise
                  set                rise 
1 2013-03-01 18:28:00 2013-03-02 08:27:00   
2 2013-03-02 18:31:00 2013-03-03 08:23:00    
3 2013-03-03 18:35:00 2013-03-04 08:19:00  
4 2013-03-04 18:38:00 2013-03-05 08:15:00   
5 2013-03-05 18:42:00 2013-03-06 08:12:00  
6 2013-03-06 18:45:00 2013-03-07 08:08:00   

#df2 my data    
  timedate
1 2013-03-01 19:00:00
2 2013-03-03 10:00:00
3 2013-03-06 00:01:00
```

I would like output like this

```
data
timedate night_day
2013-03-01 19:00:00  N
2013-03-03 10:00:00  D
2013-03-06 00:01:00  N
```

Output dput(set_rise)

```
dput(set_rise)
structure(list(set = structure(list(sec = 0, min = 28L, hour = 18L, 
mday = 1L, mon = 2L, year = 113L, wday = 5L, yday = 59L, 
isdst = 0L, zone = "WET", gmtoff = NA_integer_), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
 "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), rise = structure(list(
sec = 0, min = 27L, hour = 8L, mday = 2L, mon = 2L, year = 113L, 
wday = 6L, yday = 60L, isdst = 0L, zone = "WET", gmtoff = NA_integer_), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), night = "N"), .Names = c("set", 
"rise", "night"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Output from dput(data)

```
dput(data)
structure(list(timedate = structure(c(1362873600, 1362960000, 
1364342400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = "timedate",     row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It'd help if you added an example of the output you'd like to see.

Comment: It seems that you are messing the datetime conversion. For `set_rise` I get the `13-03-01` date (it's the year 13 and not 2013)! Just provide `set_rise` and `data` and skip how you build it. Post the output of `dput(set_rise)` and `dput(data)` after you are done. But before, check if the dates are what you are intending.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have fixed the issue with the dates and refined the posted data and posted a preferred output.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took the time to help, it is much appreciated. I have accepted the answer from nicola due to the speed, I have many large datasets (cirka 20 000 each).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a bit of preparation, but it's very fast. First, you convert your `set_rise` to `POSIXct` (instead of `POSIXlt`). Next, you convert the dates to `numeric` and combine all the values, so they form alternating values of days and nights. Then, you call `findInterval` that tells you the interval each date of `data` falls in: if the interval is odd, then it's night, otherwise is day. So:

```
#convert to POSIXct
set_rise[]<-lapply(set_rise,as.POSIXct)
#combine all the numeric values together
intervals<-c(t(matrix(c(as.numeric(set_rise$set),as.numeric(set_rise$rise)),ncol=2)))
#call findInterval and set the values, checking the parity
c("D","N")[1+(findInterval(as.numeric(data$timedate),intervals) %% 2)]
#[1] "N" "D" "N"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if I understood correctly, but here's a start:

`check_night()` checks for every value in `data$timedate` whether the it's located within one of the set/rise times in `set_rise`.

```
timedate <- c('2013-03-10 19:00:00', '2013-03-11 10:00:00', '2013-03-27 00:01:00')
data <- data.frame(timedate)
data$timedate <- as.POSIXct(data$timedate)

check_night <- function (t) {
  night <- "D"
  for (i in 1:length(rownames(set_rise))) {
    if ((t > set_rise[i,"set"]) && (t < set_rise[i,"rise"]))
      night <- "N"
  }
  return(night)
}

dplyr::mutate(.data = data, night=sapply(data$timedate, FUN = check_night))

# Output
             timedate night
1 0013-03-10 19:00:00     D
2 0013-03-11 10:00:00     N
3 0013-03-27 00:01:00     D
```

Note: There might well be a solution that does not need the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution to maj, I just did nested for loops instead of making a function and sapply. I also used strptime instead of as.POSIXct because that was giving me NA for some reason. If you have a large dataset, go with making the function and using sapply or lapply, it's easier to read and likely faster. I post this to give you some options, maj's is likely a bit faster and more elegant than mine.

```
df1<-read.csv("~/mysrc/data/sunsethelp.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
df1$set<-strptime(df1$set, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df1$rise<-strptime(df1$rise, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

timedate<-c('2013-03-01 19:00:00', '2013-03-03 10:00:00', '2013-03-06     00:01:00')
df2 <- data.frame(timedate)
df2$timedate <- strptime(timedate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

for(i in seq(nrow(df2))){
  for(j in seq(nrow(df1))){
    df2$night_day[i]<-ifelse(df2$timedate[i]>df1$set[j] && df2$timedate[i]    <df1$rise[j], "N", "D")
    if(df2$night_day[i]=="N")
      break
  }
}

#Output
             timedate night_day
1 2013-03-01 19:00:00         N
2 2013-03-03 10:00:00         D
3 2013-03-06 00:01:00         N
```